# JS Regex remove HTML Tags and Content

Tags: javascript

I am looking for a JS Regex to remove HTML Tags + the content inside. What I found so far is a simple regex to remove HTML tags, but no divs:

```
newdata.replace(/<[^>]*>/gi, '');
```

What I have:

```
Color<select>
<option value="">Show All</option>
<option value="Black">Black</option><option value="Blue">Blue</option>
</select>
```

What I need:

```
Color
```

Comment: Regex is not a good tool for this one, use DOM functions to remove all child Elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Create a dummy element** to remove Elements and keep only text nodes

```
function stripElements( str )
{
  var dummyDiv =  document.createElement( "div" );
  dummyDiv.innerHTML = str;
  return Array.from( dummyDiv.childNodes ).filter( s => s.nodeType == 3 ).map( s => s.nodeValue ).join("");
}
```

**Demo**

```js
var str = `Color<select>
<option value="">Show All</option>
<option value="Black">Black</option><option value="Blue">Blue</option>
</select>`;

function stripElements( str )
{
  var dummyDiv =  document.createElement( "div" );
  dummyDiv.innerHTML = str;
  return Array.from( dummyDiv.childNodes ).filter( s => s.nodeType == 3 ).map( s => s.nodeValue ).join("");
}

console.log( stripElements(str) );
```